# Getting rid of duplicate columns pulling through and linking output to second table like a multiway vlookup

Tags: sql

Good morning, I am newish to SQL and would really appreciate some help.
I am using the following query but do not want the "ar" column or second occurrence of the
"station_ref column". When I try to remove it in the group by area it I get an area saying it
"not in aggregate function". Also I am trying to link this output with another table named
"station_sizes" where based on wk # it assigns a size to a station.
For example if a station is small at wk 20 and standard at wk 48 then it will be a standard size. The station_size table outlines 100s of different scenarios and what size a station will be.Refer below for what the table looks like.Can you please help.Thanks!

```
wk48     | wk20  | station size
standard | small | small
```

```sql
SELECT station, ar, del_date, sum(volume) /7 as volume_ref,
CASE
    when volume_ref between 0 and 20000 then 'ds x-small'
    when volume_ref between 20000 and 36000 then 'ds small'
    when volume_ref between 36000 and 42000 then 'ds standard'
    when volume_ref between 42000 and 72000 then 'ds large'
    when volume_ref > 72000 then 'ds x-large'
    else 'ds small' end as station_ref,
CASE
    when ar = 'YES' and station_ref = 'ds small' then 'ds standard'
    else station_ref end
FROM prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp
RIGHT JOIN wbq_global.raw_station_extended_attribute
    ON prophecy_nq.na_topology_lrp.station
    = wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute.ds
WHERE del_date in ('2021-10-17', '2021-08-01', '2021-06-27', '2021-10-17')
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you  be more specific what type of SQL you are using? I have never seen `GROUP BY` followed by integers. (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Yes, I am grouping by station, ar, and del_date

Comment: Well, in that case, I would have expected to see `GROUP BY station, ar, del_date`.

Comment: The 1,2,3 does the same thing. The issue I am having is that I have 2 Case statements and its pulling in two different columns when I want it to only pull in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to get rid of `ar`, you'd need to remove it both from SELECT clause and from the GROUP BY clause
2. The "For example if a station is small at wk 20 and standard at wk 48 then it will be a standard size" part of your question is not clear. It seems that you are obtaining the "size" from `raw_station_extended_attribute` and it's not clear what's the relation between it and the week number.
3. You seem to have two `station_ref` columns and you probably need only one?
4. `Ar` seems to be a numeric column but you're comparing it with "YES"?
5. You may not be able to use the calculated columns when calculating other columns (depends on RDBMS)

```sql
SELECT station,   
  del_date,
  sum(volume)/7 as volume_ref, 
  CASE 
    when sum(volume)/7 between 0 and 20000 then 'ds x-small' 
    when sum(volume)/7 between 20000 and 36000 and max(ar) <> 'yes' then 'ds small' 
    when sum(volume)/7 between 36000 and 42000 then 'ds standard' 
    when sum(volume)/7 between 42000 and 72000 then 'ds large' 
    when sum(volume)/7 > 72000 then 'ds x-large' 
    when max(ar) = 'YES' then 'ds standard' 
    else 'ds small' 
  end as station_ref
FROM prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp 
  Right JOIN wbq_global.raw_station_extended_attribute 
    ON prophecy_nq.na_topology_lrp.station = wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute.ds 
where del_date in('2021-10-17','2021-08-01','2021-06-27','2021-10-17')
GROUP BY station, del_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure if I completely understand your question but if you mean to have only one `station_ref` column than you should only have one case since each case will produce a new column.

```sql
SELECT station, ar, del_date, sum(volume) /7 as volume_ref,
CASE
    when volume_ref between 0 and 20000 then 'ds x-small'
    when volume_ref between 20000 and 36000 and ar != 'YES' then 'ds small'
    -- note: the lower limit is the same as ds_small
    when volume_ref between 20000 and 42000 then 'ds standard'
    when volume_ref between 42000 and 72000 then 'ds large'
    when volume_ref > 72000 then 'ds x-large'
    else 'ds small' end as station_ref
-- ...
```

This should work based on the following statement:

> "So, once a condition is true, it will stop reading and return the result."
>
> – https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp